# box width 100% (letup)

Tags: css

As you can see (p1) I have got 2 mm letup but in example (p2) they haven't got letup. What I have to do to fix it?

p1

[image]

p2

[image]

My css example:

```
#head
{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #3D6AA2;
    height: 44px;
}
```

Comment: Without seeing the rest of your html I can't be sure, but have you tried setting the padding and margin to 0?

Comment: you want that white strip above your header or not ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the margin and padding from the body:

```
body {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
```

}

Answer (score 4):

Simply set your html body margin to zero pixels.

```
body {margin: 0}
```

and if you want/need to center any of the contained DIVs (which are not 100%) use;

```
body {margin: 0 auto}
```

Comment: Thanks for help. I gave you one point but I will accept Jamie Hutber answer.